# Adobe Acrobat XI changes file version automatically after pages are deleted from the document

Tags: pdf, adobe

I've got a version 1.4 PDF created by using the R-function "pdf". The file contains six pages and has 135 KB. Now I want each of these pages in a separate file in order to include it as picture in Latex. Since I have not only the Adobe Reader deleting pages isn't a problem, but after a page is deleted from the document Adobe Acrobat automatically changes the version to 1.6, which then causes problems in Latex.

I've now tried to save it as version 1.4 PDF, which itself isn't a problem, but the file size then increases from 28 KB to 759 KB and my final PDF mustn't be larger than 3 MB. I've already played a bit with the compression settings, but the size doesn't really change. Why does Adobe change the version automatically and how can I extract the pages without blowing up the size that much?

Comment: It would really help to see example documents if you want comments on this. Besides that point, how is this related to programming? I see nothing in your question that states how you are going to develop anything around this problem; it this is just a question on how to use Adobe Acrobat, you'd be better of on the Adobe forums or on a site such as superuser.com.

Comment: Oh, that's true, sorry. I want to "solve" the problem in R (basically I just need to find a way to create a new file for each plot, but the plots are done by a specific package, not the standard function), but it was a bit urgent yesterday, and therefore I tried to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Acrobat is always setting the PDF version to its own level, even if the file itself would be compliant to an earlier standard. It has been doing so since Acrobat 2…

You can control quite a few things when you do `Save as… --> Optimized PDF`. There you can also set the standard at which the document is saved, and many more things.

About the file size, it really depends on what your document contains. It is also possible that your PDF creation tool creates an incomplete document, and saving it in Acrobat will create a more complete one (think of embedded fonts, etc.).

Comment: Hmm... but the version doesn't change if I just change the content (eg delete a text field), only if I delete pages?

Comment: It probably depends on what kind of change you make. Deleting a text field can be done without touching the content of any page (as it's metadata). Theoretically splitting in pages could also be done that way, but it's likely that Acrobat has a relatively complex algorithm for it (it has to figure out what belongs to which page) and as a result that this change is catalogued internally as a "major" change, where deleting your text field isn't. All nice speculation of course :)

Comment: Ok, thanks :) I circumvented the problem by saving the files als PNGs. Not nice, but at least it worked.